# NullReferenceException When using Sqlite with WP7

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-7

I am quite new to Windows Phone dev, I am following the tutorial on the link below in which it has been explained that how one can use existing SQLite DB with WP.

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/Windows-Phone-7-Native-Database-Programming-via-Sqlite-Client-for-Windows-Phone.aspx

When I run it with my DB, I get error at the line:

```
System.IO.Stream src = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/" + assemblyName + ";component/" + dbName, UriKind.Relative)).Stream;
```

I have tried solving it by breaking it down, but it did not help me. Any help is appreciated. This is how it was mentioned in tutorial, I also change the name of the DB accordingly, but ap crashes. Please help me and pull me out of this. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that:

- the database file exists at the specified path
- the `Build Action` of the database file is set to `Resource`

Comment: I am pasting my file at the same location at which file in tutorial is placed...I have changed build action to be resource...but no effect...:(

Comment: That should work. Are you sure that the generated file path is OK? What are the values of assemblyName & dbName?